# Cancellation of User Subscription in Google In App Purchases

Tags: android, google-api, in-app-purchase

I want non auto renewable subscriptions in Google In app purchases. According to Google Docs, In App subscriptions are auto renewable which means they will be renewed after that specified time. I want non auto renewable subscriptions. So What I will do is canceling user subscription from my system. According to Google docs, If user subscription is canceled, it will remains valid until its expiration time. I have two options

1. Cancel user subscription when he subscribed as this subscription will remain valid until its expiry time.
2. Setup a scheduler which will cancel user subscription before it is renewed.

According to docs, there is parameter in response `cancelReason` which can be either 0,1 or 2

> The reason why a subscription was cancelled or is not auto-renewing.
> Possible values are
>
> 0: User cancelled the subscription
>
> 1: Subscription was cancelled by the system, for example because of a billing problem
>
> 2: Subscription was replaced with a new subscription

I want to ask, if I cancel subscription (which will be considered as subscription canceled by system) when user just subscribed, will it be valid until its expiry time? As there is no such description in Google API Docs. As for method 2 of cancellation, I had to setup a scheduler on the system which is lengthy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of a subscription is that it renews.

If you want to take a payment for a specific time period but do not want it to renew then just use in-app purchasing.

Have your users buy an in-app product and have that product "expire" after a set time period.  You can query from the system the purchase date etc. then just use the in-app "[consume](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html#consuming)" method after that time has passed.

Comment: Can we change Subscriptions to consumable?

Comment: No that is not possible but you can cancel the subscription and only allow consumable products to be purchased in future.